# Stretching height of nested elements

Tags: html, css

I have a HTML page that has some nested divs (simple div and md-card)
as in the following image:

[image]

I set 100% height for HTML page and body,
the divs (or md-card) gave 100% height or inherit.

When I stretch the page I have bottom margin like above image (I see nothing real 'bottom-margin' in the explorer (chrome) code).

how can I get full parent size like this img:[image]

Comment: Please provide some code. Pictures are great at explaining what you're after, but we can't propose a way to fix it if we don't see what it currently looks like. Also, this question is unrelated to Angular.

Comment: Pleas provide us some code (maybe JSFiddle example).

Comment: I say 'Angular' ,maybe there is any solution in Angular. as soon I put some code. Thank you.

Comment: [https://jsfiddle.net/yaelh/sxxcypgf/#&togetherjs=Canc0soNR9]

Comment: [https://jsfiddle.net/yaelh/j5kb5xxt/10/#&togetherjs=Canc0soNR9]  the update code